# How to put red asterisk in form Play 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, requiredfieldvalidator, required-field

How to replace the 'Required' to red asterisk to show that the field is mandatory?

I have these lines of code for the form; fullName and presentAddress are mandatory which I declare as @Required in models. As you can see, I hide the 'Required' message for presentAddress. Instead of hiding it, can anyone show me how to replace it with red asterisk?

```
        @inputText(newStaffForm("fullName"), 'size->50, '_label -> "Full name:")
        @inputText(newStaffForm("sex"), '_label -> "Sex:")
        @inputText(newStaffForm("presentAddress"), '_label -> "Present Address:", '_showConstraints -> false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'_help` argument, like this:

```
@inputText(newStaffForm("presentAddress"), '_label -> "Present Address:", '_help -> "*")
```

You can use CSS to color the asterisk.